# Function always returns 1

Tags: c++, function

I´m trying to write a simple branch predictor that should output either TAKEN (1) or NOT_TAKEN (0) depending on history stored in int. However it always outputs TAKEN instead of dynamicaly changing the prediction.

```
#define PHT_CTR_MAX  3
#define PHT_CTR_INIT 2

class PREDICTOR{

  private:
    UINT32  counter;

  public:

    PREDICTOR(void);

    bool    GetPrediction(UINT64 PC);  
    void    UpdatePredictor(UINT64 PC, OpType opType, bool resolveDir, bool predDir, UINT64 branchTarget);
};



PREDICTOR::PREDICTOR(void){
  counter = PHT_CTR_INIT;
}


bool   PREDICTOR::GetPrediction(UINT64 PC){
  if(counter > (PHT_CTR_MAX/2)){ 
    return TAKEN;
  }else{
    return NOT_TAKEN;
  }
}



void  PREDICTOR::UpdatePredictor(UINT64 PC, OpType opType, bool resolveDir, bool predDir, UINT64 branchTarget){

  if(resolveDir == TAKEN){
      SatIncrement(counter, PHT_CTR_MAX);
  }else{
      SatDecrement(counter);
  }
}
```

PREDICTOR::PREDICTOR is used to "build" the predictor (create arrays, set initial values...), it is called right in the beginning.

PREDICTOR::GetPrediction should return either TAKEN (when counter = 3 or 2) or NOT_TAKEN (when counter = 0 or 1).

PREDICTOR::UpdatePredictor is called after GetPrediction. It updates the predictor via resolveDir - resolveDir is the actual direction of the branch.
If resolveDir = 1 it does saturated increment of counter (saturated means it never exceeds PHT_CTR_MAX).
If resolveDir = 0 it decrements the counter.

Although this predictor is really simple it does not work. It throws out exactly same results as if I just did GetPrediction{return TAKEN} which is obviously wrong. My coding skills aren´t really great so I might have done something wrong - probably in the GetPrediction or UpdatePredictor function.

Here is an example of predictor that works just fine, although this one is little bit more complex:

```
#define PHT_CTR_MAX  3
#define PHT_CTR_INIT 2
#define HIST_LEN   17

class PREDICTOR{

  private:
UINT32  ghr;           // global history register
UINT32  *pht;          // pattern history table
UINT32  historyLength; // history length
UINT32  numPhtEntries; // entries in pht 

public:

  PREDICTOR(void);
   bool    GetPrediction(UINT64 PC);  
   void    UpdatePredictor(UINT64 PC, OpType opType, bool resolveDir, bool predDir, UINT64 branchTarget);



PREDICTOR::PREDICTOR(void){

  historyLength    = HIST_LEN;
  ghr              = 0;
  numPhtEntries    = (1<< HIST_LEN);


    pht = new UINT32[numPhtEntries];

    for(UINT32 ii=0; ii< numPhtEntries; ii++){
    pht[ii]=PHT_CTR_INIT; 
}
}

bool   PREDICTOR::GetPrediction(UINT64 PC){

  UINT32 phtIndex   = (PC^ghr) % (numPhtEntries);
  UINT32 phtCounter = pht[phtIndex];


  if(phtCounter > (PHT_CTR_MAX/2)){ 
    return TAKEN; 
  }
  else{
    return NOT_TAKEN; 
  }
  }


void  PREDICTOR::UpdatePredictor(UINT64 PC, OpType opType, bool resolveDir, bool predDir, UINT64 branchTarget){

  UINT32 phtIndex   = (PC^ghr) % (numPhtEntries);
  UINT32 phtCounter = pht[phtIndex];

  if(resolveDir == TAKEN){
    pht[phtIndex] = SatIncrement(phtCounter, PHT_CTR_MAX);
  }else{
    pht[phtIndex] = SatDecrement(phtCounter);
  }

  // update the GHR
   ghr = (ghr << 1);

   if(resolveDir == TAKEN){
   ghr++; 
   }
 }
```

This predictor works in the same way as my simple one, except that it uses an array of counters instead of single one. When GetPrediction is called the array is indexed by last 17 bits of resolveDir (branch history, global history register or ghr) that are XORed with PC (adress of current branch). This selects the appropriate counter from array that is then used to do the prediction. UpdatePredictor works the same way, array is indexed and then counter is choosen. Counter is updated with information from resolveDir. Lastly the global history buffer (ghr, branch history, call it what you want) is also updated.

Code of the `SatIncrement` and `SatDecrement` functions:

```
static inline UINT32 SatIncrement(UINT32 x, UINT32 max)
{
  if(x<max) return x+1;
  return x;
}

static inline UINT32 SatDecrement(UINT32 x)
{
  if(x>0) return x-1;
  return x;
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: What are `SatIncrement` and `SatDecrement`?

Comment: I think your biggest issue is your debugging skills need to be improved. This is not enough code for us to debug and even if it was you should have debugged before you posted.

Comment: As I have described, SatIncrement increments the counter by one, but counter never exceeds PHT_CTR_MAX. SatDecrement just decrements the counter, but it ensures that counter > 0.

Comment: Some notes on style: In C we did macros, in capitals), in C++ we don't use macros, much (don't confuse macros with constants). Unless you say ”Get would you like fries with that?” or “What is your get height?”, then don't say get in front of questions (methods returning a bool, read better if their name is an adjective, and methods returning a non-bool, read better if their name is a noun. Methods that do something read better if there name is a verb).

Comment: @drescherjm real programmers don't use debuggers: We use contracts, test driven design, and oscilloscopes.

Comment: After 30+ years of programming I still debug almost every single week (even with unit tests ...)

Comment: BTW, `PHT_CTR_MAX/2` == 1

Comment: @drescherjm if you have just written 2 minutes worth of code since the last test pass, how long does it take to find the bug? (Unit testing, or Test Driven Development?)

Comment: Could be minutes to hours.

Comment: @drescherjm The rest of the code is part of a quite big and complicated framework, I know that the framework is working ok (it was part of a competition), the issue must be either with my code that I posted uphere or during the compile process. I know that PHT_CTR_MAX/2 == 1, that should be just fine.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor the names of the functions were already part of the big and complex framework. Changing the names would be just wasted work and for me Get Prediction sounds just fine.

Comment: @Dom324 If all the things we don't know the definition of do/are what their names seem to indicate (i.e. `TAKEN` and `NOT_TAKEN` evaluate to `true` and `false`, `UINT32` is typedef for `std::uint32_t`, etc.), then I don't see any error in your code. Check that `SatIncrement` and `SatDecrement` are used correctly (e.g. taking argument by reference and modifying it; and that the first argument is supposed to be the variable and the second the limit) and that you are using the class correctly. Since we don't know the rest of the code, there is not much more to say.

Comment: Nothing looks obviously wrong about this code, but since it's not a complete program, we have to guess at what some parts actually mean.  A debugger will easily show you important clues about what's happening, like: are your functions being called when you expect, and the number of times you expect, and with the inputs you expect, or are they being called extra times you didn't expect? Is the same `PREDICTOR` object being used each time? What are the values of important variables and members before and after each call?

Comment: @user10605163 sorry, I forgot to mention TAKEN evaluates to 1 and NOT_TAKEN to 0. UINT32 means unsigned int. I´m pretty sure that SatIncrement/SatDecrement are used correctly, but will check it. I have tried to change PHT_CTR_INIT to 1 (so the counter outputs NOT_TAKEN as the initial state) and the predictor started to output NOT_TAKEN everytime. So I think it doesn´t update at all.

Comment: @Dom324 Then I suspect you are not using these two functions correctly. If you are unsure add their definitions to the question. (or the update method is not called as you expect) But more importantly you have already been given the advice to step through the code with a debugger and monitor closely how the variable values change and whether these follow your expectations.

Comment: @aschepler Debugger sounds like a really useful and awesome tool, which one would you recommend for Ubuntu? I´m little worried it´s gonna be tough to get it working with this framework. I can add an example implementation of little bit more complex predictor, but I know for sure that one is working.

Comment: gdb would be useful. If you can't debug you may want to start with just printing your variables like counter and function name for each call of UpdatePredictor() and GetPrediction

Comment: @drescherjm I´ve added an example of working predictor. There are Trace files used as an input to the framework. These trace files are using some special BT9 headers. That sounds like a hard thing to use with debuger. Printing value of counter at individual calls looks like a smart idea, I will try that tommorw. Each trace file contains several milions calls for each function, that´s gonna be a mess.

Comment: @drescherjm So I have played with it for some time, printing value of counter revealed that UpdatePredictor was the problem. I ended up redownloading the framework (to ensure that I haven´t messed it up) and I have coded SatIncrement/SatDecrement myself to ensure they´re working. Suddenly it works. I do not know why, because I have already tried to do these things earlier with no result. Big thanks everyone for help :)

Comment: In the code you have added, the functions `SatIncrement` and `SatDecrement` are used differently. They seem to take the argument by-value and return the new value. You use them as if they take their argument by-reference and modified these directly. Check the signature of the two functions and whether their parameter is a `UINT32` (by-value) or a `UINT32&` (by-reference).

Comment: @user10605163 Wow, thanks, I see it now, what a dumb mistake. For reference I´ll add the code  for `SatIncrement` and `SatDecrement`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the code doesn't work as expected is that `SatIncrement` and `SatDecrement` take arguments by-value and return the new value, which then must be assigned back to the variable that is supposed to be incremented/decremented.

```
SatIncrement(counter, PHT_CTR_MAX);
```

will pass the value of `counter` but will not modify `counter` itself. The return value with the new value is not used and so effectively this line does nothing. The same is true for `SatDecrement(counter);`.

Therefore your branch predictor never changes state and always returns the same prediction.

Fix it by following the other code example:

```
counter = SatIncrement(counter, PHT_CTR_MAX);
```

and

```
counter = SatDecrement(counter);
```

---

Given that this is an exercise you probably cannot change `SatIncrement` and `SatDecrement`, however in practice one would probably let these functions take arguments by-reference, so that they can modify the passed variable directly, avoiding the repetition of `counter` at the call site:

```
static inline void SatIncrement(UINT32& x, UINT32 max)
{
  if(x<max) x++;
}
```

If the original signature were chosen, then since C++17 one can add the `[[nodiscard]]` attribute to the function to make the compiler print a warning if the return value is not used:

```
[[nodiscard]] static inline UINT32 SatIncrement(UINT32 x, UINT32 max)
{
  if(x<max) return x+1;
  return x;
}
```

It would have warned you here and made the problem clearer.

Comment: Huge thanks for explanation, solved the problem. Branch predictor is now working as it should. Since the framework is from year 2016 `[[nodiscard]]` wasn´t avalaible back then.